# Maintain pixel-size and aspect ratio of elements in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure, aspect-ratio

After a few years of finding solutions to all my coding-problems on this site, this is my first post with (as far as I can tell) a new question!

I want to create several bar-charts from one data-set and save them as individual images. I want the image-size to scale automatically so that any given object (e.g. a 1x1 square) appears the same size on every image.

The following code produces two such images in which each 1x1 element is about 60x60 pixel, so far so good:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def barchart(bars,size,title):
    hspace,vspace = (max(size)+1,len(size))

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(hspace,vspace+1))
    fig.add_axes([0.2,0.2,0.6,0.6])
    plt.title(title)
    plt.axis('scaled')

    x_pos = xrange(vspace)
    plt.xlim(0,hspace)
    plt.ylim(-1,vspace)

    plt.barh(x_pos, size, height=1, align='center', alpha=0.5)
    plt.yticks(x_pos, bars)

    plt.savefig(title+'.png',bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.clf()

barchart(["1x1","A","B","C"],[1,3,5,2],"many short bars")

barchart(["1x1","A"],[1,17],"few long bars")
```

But I would like to do this with a different aspect-ratio, so that e.g. each 1x1 element appears as 60x30 pixel on the image. Is there a replacement for `.axis('scaled')` which does this? I have tried to scale the width in `figsize`, `xlim` and both, as well as in `.add_axes()` and several key-words in `.axis()`. They all seem to affect the final scale and aspect ratio of the images in different ways.

The exact pixel-size does not matter, whether it is 60x30 or 66x33 or otherwise, as long as it is consistent throughout all images.

Comment: scaling the figure size proportionally to the number of bars is quite imprecise because the margins are not taken into account.

Comment: But the result of `add_axes()` is supposed to be proportional to the figure size (in this case 0.6 on both axes). How can it be anything else?

Comment: You're right, this would hold for true proportionality. But here you have a `+1`.

Comment: I've figured it out from there, thanks! Some of the +/- 1 are there to have controllable margins in this particular example (bar-chart with bars centered at the tick). Is this too specific to be considered "helpful"?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the answer with the hints in the comment above and some more trial-and-error:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def barchart(bars,size,title):
    hspace,vspace = (max(size)+1,len(size))

    AR = 0.5 # x-axis will be scaled to 50%
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(AR*hspace,vspace+1)) 
    fig.add_axes([0.2,0.2,0.6,0.6])
    plt.xlim(0,hspace)
    plt.ylim(-1,vspace)

    plt.title(title)

    x_pos = xrange(vspace)

    plt.barh(x_pos, size, height=1, align='center', alpha=0.5)
    plt.yticks(x_pos, bars)

    plt.savefig(title+'.png',bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.clf()

barchart(["1x1","A","B","C"],[1,3,5,2],"many short bars")

barchart(["1x1","A"],[1,17],"few long bars")
```

The solution was to fix both the figure size and the axis limits to the same proportions and to simply leave out the `.axis('scaled')`. Then scale only the fig-width by the desired factor.